# Why have the notion of 'nice'?

Tags: scheduling, nice, priority

*I know what 'nice' is and how it maps to priority, this is not the question.*

Linux priorities range from 0-139. 0-99 is real time, 100-139 is user space. 
Nice maps onto priority:

- -20 → 100
- 0 → 120
- +19 → 139

I understand nice is user space, priority is kernel space.

But why bother with the notion of 'nice'? it seems to be a redundant measure. Under what situation would having nice be better than just simply directly influencing priority?

Is it there simply for convenience or is there a technical reason for having it?

Comment: It seems to me that `nice` *is* a way, indeed *the* [portable] way, of "directly influencing priority". By the way, real time and user space are not mutually exclusive: you can have user space processes that are real time and I also guess that you can have kernel threads that aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [nice(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nice.2.html) syscall is changing the *relative* priority (from what it was *before* that syscall). But [setpriority(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpriority.2.html) is changing the *absolute* priority.

So my understanding is that `nice(x)`  (with `x` being a very small number, e.g. between 0 and 9) is the equivalent of *atomically* doing:

```
// asssume both getpriority & setpriority syscalls are successful
int n = getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0);
n += x;
setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, n);
```

Since several processes could do likewise on the same process (e.g. calling `setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, somepid, n);` ....), you'll bettter have an *atomic* operation combining them, and that is [nice(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nice.2.html)

But the main reason is legacy and history (and backward compatibility). IIRC, in the 1980s old Unix (like SunOS3.2) had `nice`  but no `setpriority` (but I might be wrong).